# Do I need to repeat the object + を in the response to a question?

Tags: particle-を

I know that when answering a question, the topic + は is implied and left out of the response because it's redundant. Is the same true for the direct object of the verb + を?

As an example, take the question

ロバート:　ボブさんは、昨日映画を見ましたか。

Would the response be

ボブ: 　はい、映画を見ました。

Or could it just be

ボブ：　はい、見ました。

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that when answering a question, the topic + は is implied and left out of the response because it's redundant. Is the same true for the direct object of the verb + を?

Yes, it is the same.

In a Japanese language class, however, the teacher might expect you to give the full answer 「はい、映画{えいが}を観{み}ました。」.

In a real-life situation, native speakers often just reply 「観た。」、「うん、観た。」、「観たよ。」 , etc. to tell you the truth, but that does not mean that the beginning students should speak like that as well.

The verb is 「観る」 and not 「見る」 for watching something appreciatively.  But then again, if you are being taught that it is 「見る」 in a beginning class, just use it for now.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on the right kanji and explaining the nuance involved in the different use cases!